# solving exponential using Quadratic

Tags: linear-algebra, exponential-function

How should i solve $\ e^{-x}(x+1)=0.8$ by Quadratic? I don't understand how should we make it linear, i tried to expand it and it is always the extra x beside the exp(-x) that make me struggle.

Comment: There's no way of making it linear, or even solving for $x$ algebraically. Numerical solution only. Sorry ...

Comment: The closest thing you might get to an exact answer would likely lie in the use of the Lambert W function, but even that is typically approximated numerically.

Comment: You can approximate $\;e^{-x}\;$ by a linear polynomial (with Taylor, say), but that's only an approximation...Also the Lambert W function, but again: only an approximation.

Comment: oh, yes. I just come across some stats problem and i think i better find a accurate value for the mean in my distribution....

Answer (score 1):

As  Eevee Trainer commented, welcome to the world of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) !

Just rewrite
$$ e^{-x}(x+1)=a \implies e^{-(x+1)}(x+1)=\frac a e$$ to get, as shown in the Wikipedia page,
$$x=-W\left(-\frac{a}{e}\right)-1$$ For a numerical evaluation in your case, since the argument is close to $-\frac 1e$, use the Taylor series
$$W(t)=-1+\sqrt{2 e} z-\frac{2 e }{3}z^2+\frac{11 e^{3/2} }{18
   \sqrt{2}}z^3+\cdots \qquad \text{where} \qquad z=\sqrt{t+\frac 1e}$$ You would get $x\approx -0.538$ while the exact solution is $-0.528$.

As said, numerical methods have to be used in order to polish the root. The Wikipedia page tells about the Halley method used by Corless.